# INSERT INTO query does not work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two insert queries. The first one is:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblInvoices ( InvDate, ClientFK, DiscFK, ReceiptFK ) " & _
              "SELECT tblInvoices.InvDate, tblInvoices.ClientFK, tblInvoices.DiscFK, tblInvoices.ReceiptFK " & _
              "From tblInvoices " & _
              "WHERE (((tblInvoices.InvDate)=Date()) AND ((tblInvoices.ClientFK)=[Forms]![frmDisclosure]![ClientFK]) " & _
              "AND ((tblInvoices.DiscFK)=[Forms]![frmDisclosure]![DiscPK]) AND " & _
              "((tblInvoices.ReceiptFK)=[Forms]![frmDisclosure]![ReceiptFK])) "
```

This does not work, despite reworking it to make it simple (inserting basic data such as numbers instead of the links to ‘frmDisclosure’. Nothing happens – no data is shown in datasheet view. Instead I have created a form in which a procedure does the work successfully. Having run the procedure the following insert query runs successfully.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblInvoiceDetails ( DiscFK, InvoiceFK ) " & _
             "SELECT tblInvoices.DiscFK, tblInvoices.InvoicePK " & _
             "From tblInvoices " & _
             "WHERE (((tblInvoices.InvoicePK)=[Forms]![frmInvoiceAdd]![InvoicePK])) "
```

For ‘tidiness’ I’d like to get the first query to run.

Comment: Most likely your select part doesn't return any records. Create a select query without the where clause, then add criteria one by one until no records are returned to find out.

Comment: Thanks. Acting on your suggestion, the select query only works if 'ClientFK' is included. I'll keep thinking/working. Thanks.